# Ruby on Rails+PostgreSQL: usage of custom sequences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, save, rails-postgresql

Say I have a model called `Transaction` which has a `:transaction_code` attribute.
I want that attribute to be automatically filled with a sequence number which may differ from `id` (e.g. Transaction with `id=1` could have `transaction_code=1000`).

I have tried to create a sequence on postgres and then making the default value for the `transaction_code` column the `nextval` of that sequence.
The thing is, if I do not assign any value to `@transaction.transaction_code` on RoR, when I issue a `@transaction.save` on RoR, it tries to do the following SQL:

`INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_code) VALUES (NULL);`

What this does is create a new row on the Transactions table, with transaction_code as NULL, instead of calculating the nextval of the sequence and inserting it on the corresponding column. Thus, as I found out, if you specify NULL to postgres, it assumes you really want to insert NULL into that column, regardless of it having a default value (I'm coming from ORACLE which has a different behavior).

I'm open to any solution on this, either if it is done on the database or on RoR:

- either there is a way to exclude attributes from ActiveRecord's
  `save`
- or there is a way to change a column's value before insert with a trigger
- or there is a way to generate these sequence numbers within RoR
- or any other way, as long as it works :-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

For the moment, you might be stuck fetching and assigning the sequence in your ROR model like this:

```
before_create :set_transaction_code_sequence

def set_transaction_code_sequence
  self.transaction_code = self.class.connection.select_value("SELECT nextval('transaction_code_seq')")
end
```

I'm not particularily fond of this solution, since I'd like to see this corrected in AR directly... but it does do the trick.

Comment: This does create an extra query to DB, i would ideally like to be able to do insertion with sequence value in one query.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **insert the default value** in to a column in an `INSERT` statement, you can use the keyword `DEFAULT` - no quotes:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) VALUES (105, DEFAULT);
```

Or you could spell out the default, `nextval(...)` in your case. See the [manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html).

---

A **trigger** for that case is simple. That's actually what I would recommend if you want to make sure that only numbers from your sequence are entered, no matter what.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_myseq()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

NEW.mycol := nextval('my_seq');
RETURN NEW;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER myseq
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON mytable
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_myseq();
```

On a side note:
If you want to assign your own (non-sequential) numbers as 'sequence', I have written a solution for that in an answer a couple of days ago:
[How to specify list of values for a postgresql sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791896/how-to-specify-list-of-values-for-a-postgresql-sequence/7793876#7793876)

Comment: Thanks Erwin for your answer. The thing is, within ActiveRecord's save method, you cannot "send" the keyword DEFAULT within an INSERT (that would solve the case, yes). I would prefer a solution that could be 100% codified within the Ruby on Rails application, instead of programming it on the database, which would disable me from seamlessly migrating to another DBMS if needed.

Comment: @Ricardo: "seamlessly migrating to another DBMS" is a nice fantasy but it doesn't have that much to do with reality, sorry. One big downside of a trigger is that you won't be able to use it on a Heroku shared database.

Answer (score 0):

I was still experiencing this issue with Rails7 - I could see that Rails was generating a NULL in the insert, but changing the column from `integer` to `bigint` solved it. - Rails then does not supply a value for my sequenced column and the `DEFAULT nextval('number_seq')` is used.